# admin_enqueue_scripts not load custom scripts from cdn

Tags: wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I have this code in a plugin

```php
class DashboardCustomizer {

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_enquque_scripts', array( $this, 'load_custom_scripts' ) );
    }

    /*
    * Carico dipendenze CSS e JS da CDN
    */
    public function load_custom_scripts()
    {
        wp_enqueue_style( 
            'bs-css', 
            'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', 
            array(), 
            false,  
        );
        wp_register_style( 'bs-css' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 
            'popper-js', 
            'https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2', 
            array(), 
            false, 
            false 
        );
        wp_register_script( 'popper-js' );

        wp_enqueue_scritp(
            'bs-js',
            'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
            array( 'popper-js' ),
            false,
            false
        );
        wp_register_script( 'bs-js' );
        
    }
}

new DashboardCustomizer();
```

I'm trying to load some scripts from CDN but when I inspect the page it seems that they are not loaded. Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: You have some typos in the code above, including the hook and some of the enqueue functions. If this is exactly what you're running, those would prevent it from working as you expect. If not, you may want to update the code block here so others can help.

Comment: Yes I see and fixed in the dev code. Just a question, if I want to load a css from a subfolder inside my plugin folder is the `plugins_url(__FILE__)` correct?

Comment: Yes - you can see examples in the Developer Resources - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/#user-contributed-notes

Comment: As @WebElaine said, you've misspelled things:  `add_action( 'admin_enquque_scripts'`  is incorrect, for example, that's not the name of the action.  It should be `admin_enqueue_scripts` - WordPress has no idea what to do with your action.  You also have `wp_enqueue_scritp`, the `t` and the `p` are in the wrong order.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Feel free to leave an answer so I can accept it.